# How can I make legal mature female Cannabis plants to Flower in home during March (springtime)?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, reproduction

In December 2019 I purchased 4 Cannabis seeds Legally in Canada.Two of my plants are now about 100 cm tall. I am using wide-spectrum LED grow lights and have fertilized them both. I started with 16 hours light per day and now have cut back to about 12 hours per day.I was told that these seeds were not auto-flowering.These seeds were from Tweed and were labeled "Baker Street Indica". The leaves are all healthy and dark green. Now I would like to stimulate flowering. As our days are getting longer I want to trick the plants into its Fall/Autumn flowering cycle. Any good ideas ?

Comment: This question should be asked at [gardening.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about gardening rather than *biology*. It may be on-topic at gardening.stackexchange.com but please check their guidelines before re-posting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the plants in dark night for 12 h , 13h then 14h per night.
Keep the plants well fertilized with lower N , higher P and K.
Keep well watered with a dry period in between watering.
Keep the plants protected until the plants are ready to flower.